# Numbers after paragraph breaks turn into 1's

Tags: support, markdown

Numbers after paragraph breaks all turn to 1.

1. Number 1 in the list.

paragraph break

1. 2 in list.. or is it?

paragraph break

1. <- I swear I labelled this 3..

paragraph break

some characters
4.  A workaround is to place some character before the number

Answer (score 12):

It's not LaTeX; because you are starting a new paragraph with no left indentation, this resets the counter. It would happen if you have text instead of LaTeX.

If instead of a new paragraph with in-line equations you do a display equation, it works fine:

1. Numbered one, followed by `$$equation$$`
   $$\LaTeX$$
2. Number two.
   $$\mbox{More }\LaTeX$$
3. Number Three.
   $$\mbox{Even more \LaTeX.} 1\neq 3.$$

This was achieved with:

```
   1. Numbered one, followed by `$$equation$$`
$$\LaTeX$$
   2. Number two.
$$\mbox{More }\LaTeX$$
   3. Number Three.
$$\mbox{Even more \LaTeX.} 1\neq 3.$$
```

But if I place a new paragraph and start over, what happens?

1. Even though I numbered it `4`, it still shows up as `1`.

If you start a new paragraph without any justification on the left, still the same problem.

1. I numbered it five.

The source that produced this was:

```
But if I place a new paragraph and start over, what happens?

   4. Even though I numbered it `4`, it still shows up as `1`. 

If you start a new paragraph without any justification on the left, 
still the same problem.

   5. I numbered it five.
```

However, even with inline equations, if you place the appropriate justification, it works out fine.

1. Number one, followed by an equation

   $\LaTeX$
2. Number two. Followed by another equation.

   $1\neq 2$.
3. And another, giving me three

   $1\neq 3$.

But woe if I start left-justified: then

1. I get a one again.

Obtained by typing:

```
However, even with inline equations, if you place 
the appropriate justification, it works out fine.

   1. Number one, followed by an equation

   $\LaTeX$

   2. Number two. Followed by another equation.

   $1\neq 2$.

   3. And another, giving me three

   $1\neq 3$.

But woe if I start left-justified: then

   4. I get a one again.
```

Notice the justification.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a matter of TeX at all. The formatting engine, [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list), thinks you've ended your list when you start a new paragraph; the next time it encounters a numbered item, it starts a new list beginning with "1." again.

Here are several workarounds.

1. Indent your new paragraph by a number of spaces.

   This will be treated as a new paragraph within the same list item.
2. If you just want $$\LaTeX$$ on a new line, you can do a display equation like `$$\LaTeX$$`.

Sometimes, you really do want to specify your own numbering. For that, you have to escape the period following the number. Then Markdown will treat it as a regular paragraph, which is less than optimal, but at least it will leave your number alone. So `42\.` becomes

42. The answer to life, the universe, and everything.

and not

1. The answer to life, the universe, and everything.

Answer (score 6):

### Not anymore!

Numbered lists [can now start with any positive integer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/259867). (Zero, negative numbers, and infinite ordinals are still not allowed.)  The existing posts still render as they were, but will re-render according to the new Markdown version if they are edited.

Copy-pasted from the question:

---

Numbers after paragraph breaks all turn to 1.

1. Number 1 in the list.

paragraph break

2. 2 in list.. or is it?

paragraph break

3. <- I swear I labelled this 3..